# Custom autocompletion for zsh

Tags: vim, zsh

ZSH has builtin autocompletion for scp, so a command like

```
scp user@host/path/
```

would show directory listings on the remote server.

However, this does not work when opening a remote file in vim

```
vim scp://user@host/path/
```

I have googled around for documentation on the zsh autocomplete functions but it seems very complicated.  How can I enable autocomplete for vim scp?

Comment: Any progress on this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Complete autocompletion documentation is located in `man zshall` (if you don't want to view all sections in one man, see index in `man zsh`). Completion for `vim` is located in `/usr/share/zsh/$ZSH_VERSION/functions/Completion/Unix/_vim`, I guess you need to modify `_vim_files` function located at the top of the file and somehow export function _remote_files located in the `/usr/share/zsh/$ZSH_VERSION/functions/Completion/Unix/_ssh`.